# What do α, β, γ mean in a dictionary entry?

Tags: lexicography

For example, the OED has the following for the word "ask"

```
Forms: 
α. Old English ascian ...
β. Old English achsian ...
γ. Middle English aische ...
```

Do (α, β, γ) mean anything special, or are they simply equivalent to enumerating a list with (a, b, c), (i, ii, iii), etc.?

Comment: It is simply an enumeration of the list. Using lowercase Greek letters for this purpose is somewhat unusual in English context, in a German context it is seen more frequently.

Comment: https://public.oed.com/how-to-use-the-oed/key-to-symbols-and-other-conventions/ scroll down to “ Within a forms section”